# json validation c#

Tags: c#, json, сериализация, deserialize

На вход приходит строка:

```
{"policies":[{"policyNum":"","policyInsurer":"","dateSign":"","dateIssue":"","dateBeg":"","dateEnd":"","insurancePremium":0.0,"status":"","agrType":"","docSer":"","docNo":0.0,"paid":0,"postPayment":0.0,"quantity":0,"addList":[{"addIsn":0.0,"addId":"","addTypeIsn":0.0,"addTypeName":"","dateBeg":"","dateEnd":"","premium":0.0,"deltaPrem":"",}]"productItems":"","state":"",}]}
```

написан конвертер из таблички в json, соответственно, чтобы форматировать эту сроку использую:

```
jsontb.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Но на этой строчке получаю Exeption, хотя по виду json валидный, проверял так же на сайтах, все ок, не могу понять в чем проблема.

***Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'policies[0].addList', line 1, position 342."***

Comment: ...}],"productItems"...  запятую потеряли?

Comment: боже мой... спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.. "deltaPrem":"",}]"productItems":"","state":"",}]}
                 ^  ^                           ^
              проблемы тут
```

PS. Не каждый JSON-парсер допускает пустой элемент (т.е. запятая, а за ней закрывающая скобка). Поэтому обе такие запятые тоже пометил.

Comment: @Jacki Добавил пару слов..